# is there a way to find out if an object is json serializable at run time in python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, serialization, dynamic

It happens that while passing an object to a method that only accepts json, I am hitting the
`TypeError: Object of type module is not JSON serializable`

is there a way a method that can help recognize such objects before hand and without throwing an exception? For example

```
def is_json_friendly(some__object):
       if some_object.__magic_json_field:
            return True
       if type(some_object) in LIST_OF_JSON_FRIENDLIES:
            return True
       else: return False

Then I would just call the .__str__ of the object and Json.dumps(__str__returned_value)
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `try-except` to catch the exception?

Comment: @blhsing nothing is wrong with it at all, I am coding and I like to be able to code this. That is all. Lets say my interest is academic

Comment: If there is no good reason not to use `try-except`, it is your best answer.